# How to turn off the "How to use this screen" dialog

Tags: mass-effect

When ever I enter dialogs for skill advancement or inventory, I get the "How to use this screen" notification which I've had to approve always. It's not like I get it only the first time, but every time I enter this screen.

How can I turn this off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Mass Effect's main menu, select **Options**, then **Settings**, then **Tutorials** and finally deselect **Enable Tutorials** (I don't think you can deselect these one-by-one, but if you're at the stage where that's annoying you, then you should have seen them all by now anyway, and if not then they're available in the Codex).

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize those options were available in the first.